# Can't connect to projector on ubuntu 18.04 install any more, but working with live USB

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, vga

My HP Zbook 15 is no longer able to connect to a projector through its VGA-port. It has been working with Ubuntu 18.04 before and it still works with the live USB stick, but no longer with the install I have. Probably something went wrong with some driver updates/upgrades.

The difference shows up already in the `xrandr` output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm    1920x1080     60.00 +  40.00* 
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-6 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

No VGA-port (even disconnected one) is listed any more.

More outputs:

```
$ lspci -knn | grep -i vga -A 3 
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK106GLM [Quadro K2100M] [10de:11fc] (rev a1)  Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company GK106GLM [Quadro K2100M] [103c:197b]     
Kernel driver in use: nvidia    
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

and

```
$ lshw -C video

  *-display                 
      Beschreibung: VGA compatible controller
      Produkt: GK106GLM [Quadro K2100M]
      Hersteller: NVIDIA Corporation
      Physische ID: 0
      Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:01:00.0
      Version: a1
      Breite: 64 bits
      Takt: 33MHz
      Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
      Konfiguration: driver=nvidia latency=0
      Ressourcen: irq:31 memory:cf000000-cfffffff memory:70000000-7fffffff memory:80000000-81ffffff ioport:5000(Größe=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Things I have tried:

- Switching the graphics driver. Currently nvidia 396.51 is in use (accordding to Nvidia X server settings). I have switched to nvidia 390 and nouveau forth and back, but to no avail.
- trying out older linux kernels
- rebooting with the vga cable plugged in. No difference.
- updating/upgrading the system

What can I do?

Comment: Add `lspci | grep VGA -A 3` to your post.

Comment: sorry, the right command is `lspci -knn | grep -i vga -A 3`

Comment: anything more needed?

Comment: Maybe  it is  disabled from the BIOS?  Try other DP-x

Comment: Please put `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` in a pastebin etc. and post a link,  to  see what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by reinstalling the system and going back to the old linux kernel (4.15.0-29). Probably there was some inconsistency between the newer kernel and the nvidia graphics driver which caused the problem.